# char* giving different results when condition changes

Tags: c, char, md5

I am creating a simple md5 bruteforce-like program using C. The only issue I am having is that the `Found String:` output completely changes if I were to replace a part of the if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#  include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#  define SHA1 CC_SHA1
#else
#  include <openssl/md5.h>
#endif
char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}
typedef struct md5data {
char* output;
char* strin;
} md5data;
md5data getrand() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            rand();
            srand(rand());
        }
        unsigned char strin[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
        strin[i] = (rand()%94)+32;
        }
        strin[49] = '\0';
        char* string = &strin;
        char *output = str2md5(string, strlen(string));
        md5data out;
        out.output = output;
        out.strin = string;
        return out;
    }
bool starts_with(const char* a, const char* b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}
int main() {
    char input;
    printf("%s","Enter Search String: ");
    scanf("%s",&input);
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1 == 1) {
        md5data md5 = getrand();
        if(starts_with(md5.output,&input)) {
            printf("Found String: %s\nMD5: %s\n",md5.strin,md5.output);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I compile and execute, the first line of output is usually something like `Found String: 0????`

However, if I change `starts_with(md5.output,&input)` to something like `1==1` or anything like that, the output is something like `Found String: qM39$dcX_ZqFM9]?>jKhxSl@m2xrAxaL*`

What is causing the output to change and why is it happening?

Comment: Note: When `n > 0`, `snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);` still uses `16*2`.  Instead the size should be 2 less each iteration.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            rand();
            srand(rand());
        }` is quite _novel_.  Who or what text suggested that for making a random string?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on lines:

`char input;
 printf("%s","Enter Search String: ");
 scanf("%s",&input);`

`input` should be a char array (a buffer), and not a single char.
For example:

`char input[256];
 printf("%s","Enter Search String: ");
 scanf("%s",&input);`

In the current state, the `scanf` results in a buffer overflow on your stack, which causes undefined results.

Comment: I tried that and just got `Found String: >??` instead

Comment: `strin` lives only inside `getrand` because you defined it on the stack instead of using malloc(). When you call other functions, such as `strncmp` they use the stack, override `strin` and thus you get junk as an output.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up fixing it by using strcopy to transfer the string to a global variable.

Comment: `char input[256]; scanf("%s",&input);` still causes a buffer overflow when input exceeds 255 characters.  Use a width limit with `"%s"`.

Comment: An array `char input[256]` when pass to a function is decays to the address of its 1st element. So there is no need to use the address-of-operator `&` then. This `scanf(..., input)` would just do. The compiler should warn if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this issue by adding a global variable, removing md5data, and using strcpy to copy the value form getrand into the global variable.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#  include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#  define SHA1 CC_SHA1
#else
#  include <openssl/md5.h>
#endif
char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}
unsigned char stringglobal[50];
char* outputglobal;
void getrand() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            rand();
            srand(rand());
        }
        unsigned char strin[50] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
        strin[i] = (rand()%94)+32;
        }
        strin[49] = '\0';
        char* string = &strin[0];
        char *output = str2md5(string, strlen(string));
        outputglobal = output;
        strcpy(stringglobal,string);
    }
bool starts_with(const char* a, const char* b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}
int main() {
    char input[256];
    printf("%s","Enter Search String: ");
    scanf("%s",&input);
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1 == 1) {
        getrand();
        if(starts_with(outputglobal,&input)) {
            printf("Found! String: %s\nMD5: %s\n",stringglobal,outputglobal);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&input);` (which should be `scanf("%s",input)`) is as bad as `gets(input)`.  None are robust code.  Use width limits.